# Why don't Mormons sing the second verse of, "Hark! The Herald Angels Sing"?

Tags: lds, christmas, hymns

We were singing Christmas Carols tonight and noticed that in the [Mormon Hymn book](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/hark-the-herald-angels-sing?lang=eng), the following verse has been omitted from, "Hark! The Herald Angels Sing":

> Christ, by highest heav'n adored:
>  Christ, the everlasting
>   Lord;
>  Late in time behold him come,
>  Offspring of the favored
>   one.
>  Veil'd in flesh, the Godhead see;
>  Hail, th'incarnate
>   Deity:
>  Pleased, as man, with men to dwell,
>  Jesus, our
>   Emmanuel!

Why don't Mormons sing this verse?

Comment: Come Thou Fount, for some reason, is also not in the LDS hymnbook.

Comment: @Matt: It was in the hymnbook before 1985. Apparently, it was then omitted because it was not well known. Then along came Mack Wilberg's arrangment sung by the Mormon Tabernacle Choir, and now everybody wonders why it's not in the hymnbook. See http://www.ldsliving.com/10-Things-You-Didn-t-Know-about-Your-Favorite-LDS-Hymns/s/76560

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The complete text of the carol can be found [here](http://library.timelesstruths.org/music/Hark_the_Herald_Angels_Sing/). It seems that of the five verses, only verse one and three are included in the (english) Hymnbook (linked by OP).

This specific verse seems of rather trinitarian thought, that may be a reason. Seeing that two other verses have also been omitted:

> Come, Desire of nations, come,
>   Fix in us Thy humble home;
>   Rise, the woman’s conqu’ring Seed,
>   Bruise in us the serpent’s head.
>   Now display Thy saving pow’r,
>   Ruined nature now restore;
>   Now in mystic union join
>   Thine to ours, and ours to Thine.
>
> Adam’s likeness, Lord, efface,
>   Stamp Thine image in its place:
>   Second Adam from above,
>   Reinstate us in Thy love.
>   Let us Thee, though lost, regain,
>   Thee, the Life, the inner man:
>   Oh, to all Thyself impart,
>   Formed in each believing heart.

I don't know where to look for an authoritative answer, but the people responsible for Hymn books probably just didn't feel comfortable with the omitted verses. "Mystic union" is not in the vocabulary of mormons, and "Veil'd in flesh, the Godhead see" sounds too trinitarian, although it could be reinterpreted with a little effort. It's not so much that we couldn't sing these verses and reinterpret them with our doctrine, but it would not very comfortably.

Answer (score 3):

They don’t sing the second verse because the second verse confesses that Jesus is God.

“Veiled in flesh the Godhead see;
Hail the incarnate deity”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is clear and to the point, but would benefit from a source that backs it up.